# Преобразовать строку из Русских букв в hex средствами PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Приветствую!

Помогите разобраться.
Мне необходимо преобразовать имена в hex по определенным причинам.
Допустим имя "Иван" должно выглядеть так c8e2e0ed
(использовал онлайн кодировщик http://crypt-online.narod.ru/crypts/text2hex/)

Что касается PowerShell то все мои попытки получить данное значение (c8e2e0ed) окончились неудачей.

Вот все что я перепробывал:

```
PS Z:\> $string = "Иван"
PS Z:\> $data = $string | Format-Hex
PS Z:\> $data.Bytes
63
63
63
63

PS Z:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes('Иван')
24
4
50
4
48
4
61
4

PS Z:\> [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('Иван')
208
152
208
178
208
176
208
189


PS Z:\> $a = "Иван";
PS Z:\> $b = $a.ToCharArray();
PS Z:\> Foreach ($element in $b) {$c = $c  + [System.String]::Format("{0:X2}" + "", [System.Convert]::ToUInt32($element)}
PS Z:\> $c
41843243043D

PS Z:\> function ConvertTo-QdsString {param([string]$String) -join ([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($String) | % { $CheckSum = 0 } { $_; $CheckSum = ($CheckSum + $_) % 256 } { 0; 0; $CheckSum } | % ToString X2) } ConvertTo-QdsString Иван
1804320430043D040000C7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас все верно, просто вы кодировку не ту использовали для перевода...

```
PS C:\Users\User> [System.BitConverter]::ToString([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetBytes('Иван')).replace("-","")
    C8E2E0ED
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !!!